# Slow Cypher Query in Neo4j even with simple where

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have having performance problems with even simple queries.  On more complex queries it's even worse, but I thought I'd show a simple example:

If I limit the startdate like so: -

```
START event=node:`event-name-desc-search`( 'name:*mas* OR description:*mas*' ) WHERE (event.startDate < 4102444800000)  AND (event.startDate > 1386231175242)  RETURN event;
```

I get a result of 259ms.  If I remove the WHERE condition: -

```
START event=node:`event-name-desc-search`( 'name:*mas* OR description:*mas*' )  RETURN event;
```

I get a result of 12ms.

There are only 2 events in the event-name-desc-search index, so I would expect even the second result to be quicker.

I am using neo4j 1.9.5 and running the queries in the neo4j-shell, default configuration on a 2012 i7 Macbook Pro.  The results are much quicker on the second run due to caching, but searches aren't typically cachable (unless I'm missing something)

Comment: My guess that the first invocation runs on non warmed up caches. Could you run the first statement multiple times and see it it's getting faster?

Comment: Yep, but the results aren't cacheable as people could search for anything if I understand correctly?

Comment: Index lookups are not cached, but nodes and relationships and properties are, see http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/configuration-caches.html

Comment: I tried the first query again with a different search term (still getting the same single node back) and it returns in 265ms.  Seems very slow, especially for such a small dataset